# How to dynamically change the base URL in Kingsway Connection Manager

Tags: rest, ssis, kingswaysoft

I want to make a rest call with SSIS, is it possible to make the URL dynamic based on an input?

ex: 
I have an input column id.
I want below url update based on this[id]:
https://192.168.51.222/pro/api/nodes/[id]/attachments 
is it doable? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the relative path option:

**Base Url**:192.168.51.222/pro/api/nodes
**Relative path**: [id]/attachment